# What arguments are made by scholars and non-Śāktas to prove the Devī Bhāgavata isn't a major Purāṇa?

Tags: puranas, vaishnavism, bhagavata-purana, shaktism, devi-bhagavata-purana

As the title says, what are the arguments usually made by scholars and non-Śāktas (Vaiṣṇavas & others) when they say the Devī Bhāgavata Purāṇa doesn't belong in the list of 18 Mahā-purāṇas?

Answer (score 3):

The [scholarly opinion](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.94173/page/n319/mode/2up) (R. C. Hazra's) is that it was written in the 11<sup>th</sup> or 12<sup>th</sup> century A.D. so it cannot be a Mahā-purāṇa.

> The Devī-Bhāgavata, though a work of the eleventh or twelfth century A.D., claims to be the real Bhāgavata Purāṇa and includes the Vaiṣṇava Bhāgavata among the Upapurāṇas. **But it really is an Upapurāṇa adapted carefully by its author to the description of the Bhāgavata Purāṇa contained in the Matsya, Agni, Skanda, and other Purāṇas.** An examination of this work shows that its author was a Smārta Śākta Brāhmaṇa of Bengal, lived for a long time in Banaras, and then wrote this work for infusing Śākta ideas into the members of different sects by adapting it, as far as practicable, to the
> views of these sectaries.
>
> (The Cultural Heritage of India, Volume II)